# What is the concrete difference between App Shell Skeleton, MVC and the PRPL pattern?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I am used to using the MVC pattern for web development but I would like to develop a pwa. I saw information about App Shell Model, MVC, the PRPL pattern but I don't understand the concrete difference between them. And I'd like to know it.

Answer (score 1):

Based from the documentation:

[App Shell Model](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/app-shell)

> The app "shell" is the minimal HTML, CSS and JavaScript required to
>   power the user interface and when cached offline can ensure instant,
>   reliably good performance to users on repeat visits.

In short, you can think of the App Shell as your page skeleton which needs to be there even when your app goes offline. This is good for Single-Page Application with JavaScript-heavy architectures.

[Model View Controller](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvc_framework/mvc_framework_introduction.htm):

> For MVC, is an an architectural pattern that separates an application
>   into three main logical components: the model, the view, and the
>   controller.

The most used MVC framework is ASP.NET. As per structure of PWA: your website should be HTTPS enabled and your website should be responsive, thus ASP.NET provides a programming model, a comprehensive software infrastructure and various services required to build up robust web applications for PC, as well as mobile devices and works on top of the HTTP protocol. **In short, it support building for PWA.**

[PRPL Pattern](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/prpl-pattern/):

> PRPL is a pattern for structuring and serving Progressive Web Apps
>   (PWAs), with an emphasis on the performance of app delivery and
>   launch. It stands for:
>
> - **Push** critical resources for the initial URL route.
> - **Render** initial route.
> - **Pre-cache** remaining routes.
> - **Lazy-load** and create remaining routes on demand.

It is meant to serve to a client (CSS, JS and other static assets) only to what will be used by the client on a current requested page. Upon that, resource will be cached. In short, this is used for building modern PWA.

The structure of PRPL is:

- The main **entrypoint** of the application which is served from every valid route.
- The **shell or app-shell**, which includes the top-level app logic, router, and so on.
- Lazily loaded **fragments** of the app.

Comment: Thanks. PRPL corresponds to which part in MVC?

Comment: I just edited my post. PRPL has different design pattern structure from MVC.

Comment: Ok. But is it possible create a offline web app using PHP and MVC with Symfony?

Comment: Yes I think is possible. Use  Symfony for the backend because of its speed and ease of implementation. Then you could use Angular for the FE.